# Recyclerview refreshing items without even calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Let me explain you what's happening. I have a fragment and in its onCreateView() I am setting the adapter to recyclerview without any item..

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        downloadsList = new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        downloadsRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        downloadsList.clear();
        downloadAdapter = new DownloadAdapter(context, downloadsList);
        downloadsRecyclerview.setAdapter(downloadAdapter);
       }
```

Now the weird part is whenever I add items to `downloadsList` ( which is basically an ArrayList ), then my recyclerview get updated with the content available on downloadsList. I am not even calling notifyDataSetChanged() or setting new adapter again... Any help..

Comment: but still I am free to add anything to downloadsList after setting it to adapter..

Comment: show your code where you add items, and your adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reload entire `RecyclerView` using `notifyDataSetChanged()` then simple add [notifyItemInserted()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int))

when you add value in `downloadsList` then after just call

```
downloadAdapter.notifyItemInserted(downloadsList.size()-1)
```